# react native can't call .then(function(response){})

Tags: json, react-native

```
return fetch(url)
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
  return response.json();
})
```

I have a url variable. When I try to print a console.log before the first return, it works. But the current one doesn't show anything. Does that means this function `.then(function(response)` isn't called? and why is that?

Comment: So what is a `url`? Is it a valid url on the same domain or on another domain with valid CORS headers?

Comment: @zerkms I don't understand --what's "on the same domain or on another domain..."  the url will return a page with json response if I put it in the browser

Comment: Can you post the entire function, as well as the part that you say is working? Thanks.